# CUDA + OpenGL Interop without deprecated functionality

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, interop

I've previously been able to populate textures in CUDA for use in OpenGL by:

1. Create and initialize the GL texture (`gl::GenTextures()`, etc.)
2. Create a GL Pixel Buffer Object
3. Register the PBO with CUDA

In the update/render loop:

4. `cudaGraphicsMapResource()` with the PBO
5. Launch the kernel to update the PBO
6. `cudaGraphicsUnmapResource()` the PBO from CUDA
7. Load the GL program, bind texture, render as normal
8. Wash, rinse repeat.

However, I'm wondering if PBOs are still the best way to write a texture from a kernel. I've seen articles like [this one](http://rauwendaal.net/2011/12/02/writing-to-3d-opengl-textures-in-cuda-4-1-with-3d-surface-writes/#step5) ([updated for v5 here](http://rauwendaal.net/2013/04/03/cuda-5-and-opengl-interop/)) which don't appear to use PBOs at all.

I've seen some references to `cudaTextureObject` and `cudaSurfaceObject`, but their role in OpenGL interop is unclear to me.

Are PBOs still the recommended approach? If not, what are the alternatives I should be investigating?

(I'm specifically targeting Kepler and newer architectures.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see on the official example in CUDA 6 SDK, it's called "simpleCUDA2GL" in "3_Imaging" directory.
It has two different approaches to access texture inside CUDA kernel.
One of them (I think the old one) uses the PBO, and it is 3 times slower on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at this very recent CUDA GL Interop example from NVIDIA:

https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_cuda_interop_pingpong_st

Comment: It appears that this code sample uses surface references, not surface objects, like the original poster requested.